# How to add a Python module to syspath?

Tags: python

I have a file structure like this:

```
Folder
   Common
      foo1.py
   TestFolder
      foo2.py
```

I want to import in `foo2.py`  and `foo1.py`. I tried but it doesn't work on Ubuntu:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../../'))
from Common import foo1.py
```

Comment: Do you have a `__init__.py` file in your folder? this is how python creates packages and allows you to import modules from that package.http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html

Comment: I have init.py file in Common and in TestFolder

Comment: you need it in the Folder directory as well as in the sub folders if you want to import

Comment: This __init__.py is empty?

Comment: yeah it can be empty. Unless you need a certain configuration for your package but you should be fine with it being empty

Comment: @Bryan I think you are right and I added it as an anwer. Feel free to add the answer yourself and I will delete my answer. Next time feel free to post as an answer immediately.

Answer (score 167):

**How python finds its modules**

Strictly taken, a *module* is a single python file, while a *package* is a folder containing python files, accompanied by a (can be empty) file named `__init__.py`, to tell python it is a package to import modules from. In both cases, modules need their `.py` extension, but importing them is done without (see further below).

By default, Python looks for its modules and packages in `$PYTHONPATH`.

To find out what is included in $PYTHONPATH, run the following code in python (3):

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

**How to add a directory**

*Occasionally*

From within a python file, you can add path(s) occasionally to the default path by adding the following lines in the head section of your python application or script:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/your/package_or_module")
```

*For example:*

if I have a folder: `/home/myname/pythonfiles`, and I want to import the file `module_1.py`, located in that directory, I add this to the head section of my code:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/myname/pythonfiles")
```

And I can simply import the file `module_1.py` by:

```
import module_1
```

When I create a *package* and want to import module(s) from the package, I need to create a folder in `$PYTHONPATH`, containing the modules, accompanied by a (can be empty) file called `__init__.py`

*For example:*

To import from a package (folder) called `my_package` in `/home/myname/pythonfiles` , add the `/home/myname/pythonfiles` path to your `$PYTHONPATH`, like in example 1, and import the module called `module_2.py` (inside the package folder) simply with: `

```
from <packagename> import module_2
```

*Adding directories to `$PYTHONPATH` permanently:*

Add the following line to your `~/.profile` file.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/you/want/to/add
```

**Subdirectories**

From within a package, subdirectories are not included just like that; you need to "chain" the directories. To import a module `module_3.py`, inside folder `subfolder` inside folder `packagename`:

```
import packagename.subfolder.module_3
```

Given the fact that all subfolders in the package include their own `__init__.py` file.

**When a module is in the same directory as the script or application**

There is no need to insert the path to a module when it is in the same directory as the script or application, it is automatically added.

*Example:*

If I have a folder, containing `script.py` and `module.py`, I can simply import the module by:

```
import module
```

Comment: I would also like to suggest reading https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/, specially if you're targeting Python 3 (or planning to target in the future)

Comment: Why is `printenv PYTHONPATH` nothing?

Comment: `sys.path.append("/path/to/your/package_or_module")` also adds a path to the default and it is less confusing. Compared to `sys.path.insert(0,...)` which has `0` as a first argument.

Comment: @PaulRougieux: The problem with appending to the path is that your module might already exist elsewhere in the path (in an .egg file for instance) and you'll pick up *that* version of your module instead of the one in your file.

Answer (score 7):

The correct way to use relative import is:

```
from ..Common import foo1
```

And you also need a `__init__.py` in all your folders.

Comment: Thx. But if i have a module which is two folders Up how do i import that? from ....Folder is not working

Comment: Does it work with a single level?

Comment: With a single level it works.

Comment: ok, could you please accept this answer? for multilevel though you could ask a different question but first take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277200/multilevel-relative-import) and this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3617928/1154487) for the best way to call your modules inside a package

Comment: Is this true for Python 2 or Python 3?  Or both?

Comment: I would avoid relative imports there are too many ways for it to go off the rails. Unless your file structure is flat and you know it will stay that way, it is just too fraught with pitfalls. Just google problems with relative imports to see how many ways.

Comment: important updates,  in python 3,   a directory that contains a module will be already regarded as a package,  no need for the `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 3):

NB: This answer is outdated for the latest version of python 3, but is here for earlier version. For more information read the comments and https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/

---

Essentially **every** folder with python code you want to add to the syspath needs an __init__.py file. These __init__.py files can be empty.

Comment: As I understand it, this is no longer the case, the directory now becomes a "namespace".

Comment: @AaronHall interesting, source?

Comment: Try this for evidence: `python -c "from pathlib import Path; Path('ns').mkdir(); Path('ns/mod.py').write_text('''print('mod.py')'''); import ns.mod; from shutil import rmtree; rmtree('ns')"` also here's some relevant documentation, [PEP 420, which describes the addition of the namespace package semantics](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/)