# Python 'Import pyodbc' does not work in a cron task

Tags: 16.04, python, cron

Following the upgrade of a server machine to Ubuntu 16.04, all python programs started by cron fail upon the 'import pyodbc' statement.  I installed that package normally via

```
pip3 install pyodbc
```

If I create a simple program containgin just the instruction `'import pyodbc'`, it works if i run it from the command line:

```
$ python3 /home/test.py
$
```

I instructed the same program to be run from cron (here is the relevant part of crontab):

```
$ crontab –l
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 8,10,12-18 * * * python3 /home/test.py 1>>/var/log/python3.log
```

Then, in the log file, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyodbc
ImportError: No module named 'pyodbc'
```

The result is the same if I run from the 'main' cron or from a user crontab'. What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: what lies in  /home/test.py >

Comment: As described, a single line `import pyodbc`.  I edited the question to make it more visible.

Comment: Just a hunch (am on mobile atm), but cron runs with a limited set of env variables. Possibly python path is different. I believe if you set the abs path to the module, it should work.

Comment: @Jacob: There surely lies something in what you write: looking for the exact location of pyodbc, I found it under python3.4 but when i start python3, I end up in python 3.5.  Is there a way to specify that i want to install module pyodbc for python 3.5?  Or is it better to eliminate (how?) python 3.4?

Comment: Isn't it possible to just add the path (in the script) to the module, like: http://askubuntu.com/a/471168/72216

Comment: Thank you for your help, it put me on the right track.  I could finally solve the problem.  Remains the question of installation (see my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, thanks to the suggestion of Jacob Vlijm, I finally found out the solution: the package '`pyodbc`' had been installed under user1 (`/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/`).  As I logged in as user1 in my terminal, the program could find the module.  Using `cron`, I usually run the programs under another user (`user2`).

That was the problem.  Running in cron via user1, everything was OK.
The last question I will investigate is why the command '`pip3 install pyodbc==3.0.10`' made the package available to user1 and not to all users.

Comment: Because `pip3 install` by default only installs locally for the user invoking the command, which is `user1` in this case.

Comment: You could install it for all users by getting it from the official Ubuntu repositories: `sudo apt install python3-pyodbc`

Comment: ...I nevere pip.

Comment: @edwinksl: thanks.  I have then incorrectly interpreted the official documentation of python (https://packaging.python.org/installing/#use-pip-for-installing) specifying how to install just for one user.  I derived from it that if I do not use the flag '--user', the installation is for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Alright , make your program like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pyodbc
```

Give executable permissions like

```
chmod +x filename.py
```

and now add it cron and lets see.

Comment: I tried your proposal running both 'python3 /home/test.pt' and '/home/test.py': that works in terminal but result in an ImportError in cron.

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen have you add in the cron as normal script like " ./scriptname.py"

Comment: No, exactly what I wrote: `python3 /home/test.py` and `/home/test.py` I did not want trouble with relative path.

Comment: But you still can something like `/home/./test.py`