# Python script on boot, module import error

Tags: boot, scripts, python, mysql

I don't have much experience with Python, but I have made a script that reads temp and pressure and sends it to a mysql database. When I log in ssh and run the script manually everything works. But when I put the script to start at boot, it says:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/code1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ImportError: No module named mysql.connector
```

Same with another boot option on another raspberry pi:

```
systemctl status sample.service
● sample.service - My Sample Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sample.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-07-11 13:49:32 CEST; 4min 35s ago
  Process: 555 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/code1.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 555 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 11 13:49:31 localhost systemd[1]: Started My Sample Service.
Jul 11 13:49:32 localhost python[555]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jul 11 13:49:32 localhost python[555]:   File "/home/pi/code1.py", line 1, in <module>
Jul 11 13:49:32 localhost python[555]:     import mysql.connector
Jul 11 13:49:32 localhost python[555]: ImportError: No module named mysql.connector
Jul 11 13:49:32 localhost systemd[1]: sample.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 11 13:49:32 localhost systemd[1]: sample.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running Raspbian or Ubuntu?

Comment: And in either case did you install the Python libs containg the MySQL connector?

Comment: I had something similar: [Python 'Import pyodbc' does not work in a cron task](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816171/python-import-pyodbc-does-not-work-in-a-cron-task).  The reason was that the package had been installed using another name.  So, maybe the first thing to do is to create/modify your crontab/servvie defintion (I am not sure how you start the program at boot)  to use the same userid in ssh and cron/service.

Comment: I am running Raspbian buster. I think the Mysql connector python libs are installed since it is working when I run it manually in ssh...

Comment: Marc, I can try to modify the definition. Its like this: [Unit]
Description=My Sample Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/code1.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Comment: post the output of `pip --version` and `python --version`

Comment: pip --version
pip 19.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)               python --version
Python 2.7.16

Comment: I dont think I have cron. cron --version
cron: invalid option -- '-'
usage: cron

Comment: Ok. systemd 241 (241)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid

Comment: nm, the answer that I was looking for is in the original post.

Comment: Instead of calling python directly in the service, create an .sh file, call your python script from that, and call the .sh script in your service.  That will allow you to do a bit more debugging in the shell script.

Answer (score 2):

After some testing with different commands. I finally got it to work.
I had to install it globally like rtaft suggested.
I did it with this command:  sudo -H pip install mysql-connector

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Either it is installed in your home directory or you are using virtualenv.  Install it globally.

```
sudo pip install mysql-connector-python
```

If you are using virtualenv, you need to wrap it in a shell script and activate it in that script, ie myscript.sh:

```
source ~/pathtoproject/venv/bin/activate
python ~/pathtoproject/myscript.py
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it now!

Comment: Im not using virtalanv. How to install globally? I only ran sudo pip install mysql-connector-python from my ssh login as pi user, but it didnt help.