# How to install WiFi drivers for HP notebook laptop with RTL8723DE on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, hp, realtek-wireless

I am having issue with HP notebook laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 installed. It is not detecting any WiFi signal. Looks like driver issue. Tried to find driver on HP website but did not get it. 
How do I find and install third party driver?

```
lspci -knn | grep Net
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the output of the following command in Terminal: `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`.

Comment: We need more info. Please help us help you by doing `lspci | grep -i wireless && sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name && sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-manufacturer && sudo lshw | grep product | head -n1 && lshw | grep -v "loop" && lsb_release -a` and paste the result into your question after clicking [edit].  Please do not click on Add Comment as new comments can shove old comments off screen; your information about your PC and the Ubuntu installation should all go in the Question so we can all see your findings.

Comment: @K7AAY re: "Please do not click on Add Comment as new comments can shove old comments off screen". This is incorrect.

Comment: @heynnema, would you please be so kind as to look at comments for https://askubuntu.com/questions/1157538/python-script-on-boot-module-import-error which is just one example. Six comments are shoved off the screen there.

Comment: @K7AAY they are displayed if you just click the "show 6 more comments" link, and then all comments are visible. Also, you use your "canned" comment almost everywhere, and I'm not sure that the commands that you request are really required info as it applies to the question. Like "dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name && sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-manufacturer". Why?

Comment: They are, indeed, pushed off the screen. I have seen many OPs overlook them. In addition, a standardized request for hardware and software info is something I would like to encourage; the constant on-off, bespoke, boutique responses of folks trying to help consumes much time and energy, and I want to lead from the front in encouraging us to think about how we might better serve our OPs eith a methodical and consistant approach (but, then, I was raised a Methodist).

Comment: @K7AAY but... the info that you request makes no sense at all... like the 2nd lshw that you request "lshw | grep -v "loop"" tells you what, exactly? And knowing the baseboard-product-name and baseboard-manufacturer tells you what exactly? It's like a collection of commands that you've learned, and you throw them all up against the wall, and see what you get back. The first thing that you learn here on AU is that if you ask for too much info at once, that you'll get little info back from the OP at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96103/discussion-between-k7aay-and-heynnema).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using HP Notebook XXXX series laptop with rtl8723de chipset. To install the driver follow below commands,

```
git clone https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git -b 5.0-up

dkms add ./rtl8723de

dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414

depmod -a

reboot
```

To uninstall follow below commands:

```
rmmod -f 8723de

dkms uninstall rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414

dkms remove rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 --all

depmod -a

reboot
```