# How do I find the icon files used by non-default status menus (aka indicators)?

Tags: unity, icons, indicator

I'd like to find the location of the icons used by some non-default [status menus](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/unity-menubar-intro.html) (also called application indicators or indicator applets).

[image]

Where are these icons image files located?

In my screenshot I have ownCloud and Radiotray, but I would like a general answer not specific to these particular icons please. I don't know the file names or file types so searching is difficult.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Default location for non-default indicator icons?

There is no default location where these icons are stored. Any application (-developer) can store them where it is considered appropriate.

*However*, the good news is that indicators usually do not install endless lists of files and images. We can limit our search by (apart from looking into the code) looking into the output of the command:

```
dpkg-query -L <packagename>
```

In my example of

```
dpkg-query -L placesfiles
```

[image]

this would among others, output the following images:

```
/opt/placesfiles/images/dir_icon.png
/opt/placesfiles/images/placesfiles64.png
/usr/share/pixmaps/placesfiles.png
```

...Which would make the search quite limited.

From man `dpkg-query`:

```
   -l, --list [package-name-pattern...]
          List packages matching given pattern. If no package-name-pattern
          is  given,  list all packages in /var/lib/dpkg/status, excluding
          the ones marked as not-installed (i.e.  those  which  have  been
          previously purged). Normal shell wildcard characters are allowed
          in package-name-pattern. Please note you will probably  have  to
          quote  package-name-pattern to prevent the shell from performing
          filename expansion. For example this will list all package names
          starting with “libc6”:
```

In the case of **Radiotray**, I found the following `.png` files (running `dpkg-query -L radiotray | grep png`):

```
/usr/share/radiotray/images/radiotray_connecting.png
/usr/share/radiotray/images/radiotray_on.png
/usr/share/radiotray/images/radiotray_off.png
/usr/share/radiotray/images/radiotray.png
/usr/share/pixmaps/radiotray.png
```

### If we *really* need to find out, searching the code

...we can look through (inside) installed files for matches of the string "icon". Many of the indicators are written in one of the script- languages (like `python`), which means they are very well search-able.

#### An example

Again using the `radiotray` example

```
dpkg-query -L radiotray | xargs grep icon
```

in the output we find a.o.:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/radiotray/SysTrayGui.py 
                 self.icon.set_from_file(APP_ICON_CONNECT)
```

Looking into the file `SysTrayGui.py`, we can see:

```py
from lib.common import APPNAME, APPVERSION, APP_ICON_ON, APP_ICON_OFF, APP_ICON_CONNECT, APP_INDICATOR_ICON_ON, APP_INDICATOR_ICON_OFF
```

From this, we can conclude the mentioned icons are defined in the module `common` inside the (sub) directory `lib`. (See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/471168/72216) how python finds it modules, section *Subdirectories*)

In this module, we can read the section:

```py
# Media path
if os.path.exists(os.path.abspath('../data/images/')):
    IMAGE_PATH = os.path.abspath('../data/images/')
else:
    IMAGE_PATH = '%s/%s/images' % (datadir, APPDIRNAME)

# Images
APP_ICON = os.path.join(IMAGE_PATH, 'radiotray.png')
APP_ICON_ON = os.path.join(IMAGE_PATH, 'radiotray_on.png')
APP_ICON_OFF = os.path.join(IMAGE_PATH, 'radiotray_off.png')
APP_ICON_CONNECT = os.path.join(IMAGE_PATH, 'radiotray_connecting.gif')
APP_INDICATOR_ICON_ON = "radiotray_on"
APP_INDICATOR_ICON_OFF = "radiotray_off"
APP_INDICATOR_ICON_CONNECT = "radiotray_connecting"
```

...and here we are...

#### Exceptional situations

With practical all of my indicators, I managed to find the corresponding icons using the method(s) above.

In turns out to be possible however, to compile images together with the code into a single executable. No need to explain that in such cases you will not find a separate image, nor will you be able to replace them without editing the code and recompile.

The case of owncloud seems to be such a case. Using the above method(s) showed a set of icons was installed inside `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/<size>/apps`. None of these icons turns out to be used however in the indicator *on ubuntu*.

OP did quite some work before (and after) he asked this question. One of them was to run:

```
gdbus call --session --dest com.canonical.indicator.application --object-path /com/canonical/indicator/application/service --method com.canonical.indicator.application.service.GetApplications
```

... which gives us quite some useful information. The output included a section:

```
('146028888067', 2, 'org.kde.StatusNotifierItem-22055-1', '/StatusNotifierItem/menu', '/tmp/iconcache-50ePXx', '', '', '', 'owncloud', 'ownCloud')
```

Looking into the directory `/tmp/iconcache-50ePXx`, I found the exact icons that were used by the indicator:

[image] [image] [image]

... which seems to prove these icons are generated on the fly; closing owncloud makes the directory and its icons vanish.

It turned out to be possible to change the indicator's icon by replacing these icons:

[image]

which proves these are indeed the icons we were looking for.

To automate what I did manually however, would requires a script/wrapper, since the created directory's name is changed every time owncloud is launched. The most convenient option would of course be that the owncloud-client's code would be changed.

See also our discussion [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50879/discussion-between-jacob-vlijm-and-tom-brossman).

To be continued...

Comment: Doesn't `dpkg -L` do the same thing?

Comment: @KazWolfe apparently, here it is not mentioned though: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/dpkg.1.html

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful for finding the Radiotray icons. I'm after the ownCloud monochrome icon from my screenshot ([example from ownCloud source code on GitHub here](https://github.com/owncloud/client/blob/master/theme/white/state-ok-128.png))- and it isn't among the results returned with `dpkg-query -L`. Searching with `find / -name state-ok -type f` looks to have stalled but I'll leave it running overnight.

Comment: @TomBrossman I am sure we can find out. I will install ownCloud to see.

Comment: Great, thanks. The package is `owncloud-client` from the opensuse PPA.

Comment: @TomBrossman you are not using the Ubuntu ppa? (I assume you do?)

Comment: Yes, the Ubuntu 16.04 packages from the opensuse-hosted PPA (not for the open SUSE distro of course...) Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @TomBrossman The server might be temporarily down, I get 404 -not found error on some parts.. Looking into the downloaded .deb file, owncloud installs quite some icons in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/<size>/apps`  though. Unfortunately, the .deb file does not install: `Errors were encountered while processing:` I will retry later...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50879/discussion-between-jacob-vlijm-and-tom-brossman).

Answer (score 4):

#### Icons and their potential locations

There's two ways indicator could employ icons:

- Custom icon. This typically goes into `/usr/share/pixmaps/` , although it's possible some of the authors send indicator icons to other directories. Jacob Vlijm, whose answer is on this page and who is also author of SpaceView indicator, for example, chose to place icons for that indicator into `/opt/spaceview/icon`. With these type of icons it's slightly tricky but not complex - use `dpkg -L <package name>` or `cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/PACKAGE.list` and search for an icon file, with `.png` or `.svg` extension. These are most typical
- Standard, theme-specific icon. These typically can be found in `/usr/share/icons` folder. For instance, in my indicators such as Udisks Indicator, I frequently rely on what's in `/usr/share/icons/gnome` , since these are standard and come with any Ubuntu installation. If you don't find an icon from querying `dpkg` , chances are the package uses a standard icon.

#### Going to the source

If an indicator is written in Python or Ruby, looking through source code for clues can be relatively easy, since these are scripts, and it is sufficient to use `grep` to search through the source code. Compiled languages such as C and Vala don't come with source code, so you would have to obtain it, either via `apt-get source package-name` or from wherever you obtained the package. ( Adventurous users could use `hexdump` or decompile the executable file, but IMHO it's too much work just for curiosity about an icon ).

**NOTE**: if an icon resides in one of the standard directories, such as `/usr/share/icons/` or `/usr/share/pixmaps`, the author of the software may choose to call the icon simply by name, without extensions. For example, in my `udisks-indicator` I use this line to call one of the standard icons:

```
self.app.set_icon("drive-harddisk-symbolic")
```

Notice the lack of `.svg` or `.png` extension. Thus, in this case, we have a name of the icon, and we can locate it using Linux standard commands such as `locate` or `find`.

#### Search using standard Linux tools

If you really want to have a command for searching icons, just use this simple combination:

```
dpkg -L <Package name here> | xargs file  | grep -i image
```

Here's an example.  I know for a fact that indicator diskman uses a custom icon. So what does this command tell us ?

```
$ dpkg -L indicator-diskman | xargs file  | grep -i image                                                                
/usr/share/indicator-diskman/images:                    directory
/usr/share/indicator-diskman/images/drive-harddisk.svg: SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image
/usr/share/indicator-diskman/images/media-optical.png:  PNG image data, 64 x 64, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
/usr/share/indicator-diskman/images/disks.png:          PNG image data, 64 x 64, 8-bit gray+alpha, non-interlaced
/usr/share/indicator-diskman/images/locked.png:         PNG image data, 16 x 16, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
/usr/share/indicator-diskman/images/lock.svg:           SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image
/usr/share/indicator-diskman/images/unlocked.png:       PNG image data, 16 x 16, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
/usr/share/indicator-diskman/images/media-eject.svg:    SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image
/usr/share/indicator-diskman/images/disk.png:           PNG image data, 32 x 32, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
/usr/share/pixmaps/indicator-diskman.png:               PNG image data, 64 x 64, 8-bit gray+alpha, non-interlaced
```

Notice the `/usr/share/pixmaps/indicator-diskman.png` the last image, which is what the indicator actually shows on the panel.

And what if the indicator uses a standard icon ? Well obviously there will be no output:

```
$ dpkg -L udisks-indicator | xargs file  | grep -i image                                                                 

$
```

#### Conclusion

While there's no set standard, there's set of typical places where icons go, and we can use `dpkg` to query information about what files come with each specific package. Finally, maybe it's not the most technical suggestion, but consider sending developers an email or stopping by their IRC or chat, and simply asking them "Hey, what icon does your indicator use?". Developers usually are glad to hear from people who use their software and won't mind to answer a quick question.

Comment: Thanks, this answer was also very helpful but my ownCloud desktop sync is doing something strange with the icons and I hope to figure that out too.

Comment: @TomBrossman by doing something strange, what exactly do you mean ?

Comment: ownCloud's Desktop Sync application installs a range of icons that it does not use. I had hoped to customise and replace them but since it generates them on the fly in `/tmp` it's not practical. Customising them for most applications is easy using your answer though, since they use the installed icon set(s).