# How do I change the Mega panel icon?

Tags: icons, themes, panel, mega

I want to change Mega's panel icon to better fit with my theme but I can't figure out what to name the icons. Has anyone managed to change Mega's icon?

I know how to change specific icons, but I just don't know what what name Mega uses for its panel icons.

[image: Mega looks out of place, doesn't it?]

Comment: Do you know where the icon is located?

Comment: I don't. I've tried doing a search in /usr/share/ and I also tried doing a more general search in my entire computer for "mega" to try and find any relevant folders but I couldn't find anything. So I fear it might be a hard-coded icon

Comment: Using the method in this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/865149/72216 I found five icons: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/mega.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/mega.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/mega.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/mega.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/mega.png Which one is exactly used for the panel, you'd have to try. I'll mark it as a dupe, but if it doesn't solve, please leave a comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the icon files used by non-default status menus (aka indicators)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/832568/how-do-i-find-the-icon-files-used-by-non-default-status-menus-aka-indicators)

Comment: Thanks, but those aren't the right icons. Those only change the apps icon in things like the dash, but not the panel.  Mega uses at least three different icons in the panel depending on its status.

Comment: OK, I'll retract my vote, but I am pretty sure the issue is then the same as described in the section ***Exceptional situations*** in the linked dupe. These icons are simply all megasync installs. It is a pretty short list.

Comment: Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I sent an email to Mega support and they told me the icon is hardcoded and thus cannot be changed.

Comment: Exactly. like here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/832568/how-do-i-find-the-icon-files-used-by-non-default-status-menus-aka-indicators/865149#865149 see "Exceptional situations".

Answer (score 1):

After seeing various forums, I finally found out that Mega stores its panel icons in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/status`. I think it is possible to change the icons by copying other images to that directory with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Megasync checks `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/status` before checking `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/status`. Thus, if you place files with the following names:

- megaalert.svg
- megalogging.svg
- megapaused.svg
- megasynching.svg
- megauptodate.svg
- megawarning.svg

in this `~/.local[...]` path directory, it should load those icons instead.