# Where to find Icon in .desktop file mantioned without path?

Tags: unity, icons, paths

Here is an example for Hydrogen Drum Machine

```
[Desktop Entry]
X-AppInstall-Package=hydrogen
X-AppInstall-Popcon=208
X-AppInstall-Section=universe

Name=Hydrogen
Comment=Create drum sequences

GenericName=Drum Machine

Version=1.0

Type=Application
Categories=AudioVideo;Audio;Qt;

MimeType=text/xml;

Exec=hydrogen %F
TryExec=hydrogen
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true

Icon=h2-icon

X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=app-install-data
```

But I can not find anywhere the icon.

The same with Atom IDE or other software. Where they store their icons? I don't want search through ** all the time a need an icon >_<

Comment: Try `locate h2-icon*` to find the icon file. Usually the icons are in `/usr/share`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is *almost* a dupe of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832568/how-do-i-find-the-icon-files-used-by-non-default-status-menus-aka-indicators/865149#865149), and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/435612/72216) is also useful to read, but for reasons of findability, I will post an answer here.

#### How to find installed files of your application

for globally installed applications, by default, icons in `/usr/share/pixmaps` do not need the path, and if you do not use their path in a `.desktop` file, you *must* not use their extension as well.

In this case however, that is not the case, as you can see in the output of

```
dpkg-query -L hydrogen
```

which shows you where the icon is located.

from man dpkg:

```
   dpkg-query actions
           
           ------------------

          -L, --listfiles package-name...
              List files installed to your system from package-name.
```

Then:

```
$ dpkg-query -L hydrogen | grep h2-icon
```

returns:

```
/usr/share/hydrogen/data/img/gray/h2-icon.svg
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/h2-icon.svg
```

Either one of these two is your icon. My guess is that it is the second one :).