# cannnot import module

Tags: 14.04, python3

I can not import my module containing python class. Everywhere it's said that if both files are in the same directory import should work fine but it seems like it doesn't. I have the following structure of folders which ar ein the same folder:

```
chapter_9 folder contains files:
9-10.py
9-1.py
9-4.py
9-7.py
9-9.py
restaurant.py
```

when I type the following in the 9-10.py file

```
import restaurant
```

it's saying "No module named restaurant." Why it is so? Both files are in the same folder. Tell me please if you know where I should dig?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried making an empty file called `__init__.py`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory

Comment: I have tried to create empty __init__.py. No result. Also I tried to call like this:
from .restaurant import Restaurant
and then I get the error:
No module named '__main__.restaurant'; '__main__' is not a package

Comment: It' said in the link you have posted previously
https://askubuntu.com/questions/470982/how-to-add-a-python-module-to-syspath
that if it's module and it's in the same folder as the calling app or script I can simply write 
import restaurant
and this should work but it doesn't. So seems confusing to me

Comment: also making __initi__.py is required only if it's package but I have simple module. So no need for me doing that as I get this.

Comment: @Azat In pycharm, did you open the chapter_9 folder or only the separated python files ?

Comment: @yoann_dev, hmmm... I have created chapter_9 folder and then inside I have created python files and then opened them. Also I even incidentally have added to my sys.path variable the path to the chapter_9 folder and this also didn't help.(import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/your/package_or_module") Also there is  ' ' in my sys.path variable which means it should search for the modules in the current location.

Comment: import restaurant works perfectly in the shell but doesn't work in pycharm. it's something to do with pycharm but I don't know what exactly

Comment: @Azat I added a new part in my answer to Open projet in Pycharm

Answer (score 1):

## Open project in PyCharm

You need to open the whole `chapter9` folder in pycharm. In Pycharm do :  File > Open and choose chapter9 folder.

[image]

Projet folder appears in left side of Pycharm

[image]

To finish you can check python interpreter and root directory. Go in File > Settings > Project: Chapter9.

- Project Interpreter must be valid.
- Project Structure must have a valid content root (`chapter9` folder)

[image]

## PYTHONPATH

To ensure that Python search modules in your directory, you can set `PYTHONPATH` environnement variable by the following command :

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path_to/chapter_9 folder/
```

Documentation to `PYTHONPATH` : https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

Comment: when I type
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path_to/chapter_9 folder/
pycharm is underlining it with red saying that it's unresolved reference.