# Python - Import no module found

Tags: python

I am running python 3.5.5 and have the following folder structure.

```
sgan/
    scripts/
        train.py
    sgan/
        losses.py
        models.py
        utils.py
        data/
            loader.py
            trajectories.py
```

I am in folder `~/sgan` but when I ran `python scripts/train.py` I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./scripts/train.py", line 14, in <module>
    from sgan.data.loader import data_loader
ImportError: No module named 'sgan'
```

What is the issue here ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/470982/how-to-add-a-python-module-to-syspath/471168#471168

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/37233239/3701431  You'd basically need `__init__.py` in each subdirectory

Comment: I tried putting in train.py import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/ast/sgan/sgan/") but it did not work

Comment: I also tried import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/ast/sgan/sgan/data") but it did not work

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy but i read that __init__.py is only for python 2

Comment: help me pls !!!

Comment: here is the code https://github.com/agrimgupta92/sgan

Comment: if u dont know how to solve it then i think ill create another thread

Comment: ok i posted a new thread. hopefully you all will be able to learn something as well since u cant solve my problem

Comment: Don't just create new threads for the same problem. Be patient, nobody is getting paid to help you. Just do what @SergiyKolodyazhnyy said and put an empty `__init__.py` file in `sgan/sgan/` and `sgan/sgan/data/` so Python knows it's package. `__init__.py` is definitely not for Python 2 only.

Comment: @karel ya thats the new post ty

Comment: @kong That file is the standard way of creating Python packages, and it works for Python 2 and 3 just fine.